# Analogy for htmls <script src=" "> tag for xaml

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml

What is analogy for HTML's `<script src="">` tag for adding external javascript, to add C# script to XAML?

Answer (score 0):

It does not work exactly the same way. You can use a Javascript API for Silverlight instead of a managed server - side event handling class. Your XAML page will use one (the JavaScript API) or the other (the managed class) depending on the presence of the **x:Class attribute** in the root element of your XAML page. If the x:Class attribute is not there it will use the JavaScript API; otherwise it uses the managed class.

You uses the same mechanism `<script src="...">`, but you uses it inside the HTML of the hosting page. See more on this [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIbrary/cc903955(v=vs.95).aspx)